# AngularJS fail to inject a service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a simple service which grab data from HTTP end point send it back to controller.

I also implemnted caching in the service however, i get this error `TypeError: undefined is not a function` on this line of code in my controller

```
myappApi.getItems().then(function(data)
```

I tried to figure out why i couldn't.
 here is the controller code:

```
.controller('ItemsCtrl',['$scope','myappApi',function($scope, myappApi){
    myappApi.getItems().then(function(data){
        $scope.items = data;
    });
}])
```

As am using Ioniframework here how i injected my services in the `app.js`:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'myApp.controllers', 'myApp.services', 'angular-data.DSCacheFactory'])
```

and here is the code of my service:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myApp.services',[]).factory('myappApi', ['$http', '$q', '$ionicLoading', 'DSCacheFactory', myappApi]);

    function myappApi($http, $q, $ionicLoading, DSCacheFactory) {


        self.itemsCache = DSCacheFactory.get("itemsCache");

        //to re-use expired cached data if no internet connection
        self.itemsCache.setOptions({
            onExpire: function (key, value) {
                getItems()
                    .then(function () {
                        console.log("items items Cache was automatically refreshed.", new Date());
                    }, function () {
                        console.log("Error getting data. Putting expired item back in the cache.", new Date());
                        self.itemsCache.put(key, value);
                    });
            }
        });

        function getItems() {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                cacheKey = "items",
                itemsData = self.itemsCache.get(cacheKey);

            if (itemsData) {
                console.log("Found data inside cache", itemsData);
                deferred.resolve(itemsData);
            } else {
                $http.get("services/data.json")
                    .success(function(data) {
                        console.log("Received data via HTTP");
                        self.itemsCache.put(cacheKey, data);
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    })
                    .error(function() {
                        console.log("Error while making HTTP call.");
                        deferred.reject();
                    });
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }

        return {
            getItems: getItems
        };
    };
})();
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: in your controller you have `vascularApi`, that isn't defined anywhere that I can see

Comment: i edited my question it's not really the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in the angular-cache file CHANGELOG.md :
"- Angular module renamed to *angular-cache*
- *DSCacheFactory* renamed to *CacheFactory*"

You will have to change:

1. app.js:
   instead of 'angular-data.DSCacheFactory' use 'angular-cache'
2. service.js
   instead of 'DSCacheFactory' use 'CacheFactory'

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've declared the myappApi factory before the myappApi function is actually defined. Try something like:

```
angular.module('myApp.services',[]).factory('myappApi', ['$http', '$q', '$ionicLoading', 'DSCacheFactory', 
function($http, $q, $ionicLoading, DSCacheFactory) {
  // myappApi code
}]);
```

Comment: Same error. i also didn't get the difference between the two methods of implementing services

Comment: Yup. Looks like a typo. Gotta pass your service function to the module() method. :)

PS. Have a Plunkr you can point at?

Comment: That's a good point. If the angular module is already defined somewhere, you'll want to drop the [] in the module declaration. Or else, you're re-declaring the module. Secondly, the way I did it just makes sure the function is defined by the time you declare the factory. When the first line is executed in your code example, the `myappApi` function isn't defined yet. It gets defined on the next line. +1 on the plunkr

Comment: I dropped the [] change my code to the way in your answer, i got new error.Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp.services' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.6/$injector/nomod?p0=myApp.services